# How to trace from where i am getting ct_cmd_alloc error thrown in my application

Tags: c++, sybase

I have an application Where I am running a process. while this process runs I get a 
`ct_cmd_alloc` error saying malloc failed . I understand that this error is thrown when 
the allocation of memory space fails . But I want to know if there is any other reason
Where i should concenterate to find this error .

My most important concern is `How can i actually pin point where and what in my code 
is resulting  into this error. can i use gdb ,mdb or say d-Trace to pin pointy the location 
and if so How can i proceed for that.`

Answer (score 1):

If you run your program in gdb and cause the exception to happen, you can type the command `where` to get a stack trace.

Make sure to compile your program with debug flags enabled (`-g`)

Comment: Do you mean to say i should run my process and then wait for core dump and then analyse it using gdb ?

Comment: @Ritesh: You need to run your process from within gdb.

Comment: @Hippo I run my process through command line . can you give me some insight on how to run it from within gdb ?

Comment: @Ritesh: Googling should give you some great tutorials. Here's one: http://www.unknownroad.com/rtfm/gdbtut/gdbuse.html#RUN

Comment: @Hippo When i run my process through command line . It will go through various cc files . Say the command line i use to run my process is ` my_process < a1.txt ` . The link that you have passed says me   `(gdb) run arg1 "arg2" ... `  modifying this as 
`(gdb) run my_process < a1.txt`. Will this suffice my requirement ?

Answer (score 1):

In gdb you can put a catchpoint on the throw command. This will interrupt anytime an exception is thrown:

```
(gdb) catch throw
```